# How do i use variable within a variable second variable value give single qutaion?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$cod=set_value('code')  ;   

$where='`code`= '.$cod ' ';
```

result should be like `code ='some value'` but when i print give the error

Comment: i don't get it either, but it smells like SQL injection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt understood your question properly but i think this is what you need...

```
$where="'code=".$cod."'";

Or


$where="code='".$cod."'";
```

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to answer a question if you don't understand it (though to be fair I don't think anyone could understand this one)